# channelRead() doesn't forward message to channelRead() in next ChannelInboundHandler

Tags: java, networking, netty

I have a netty server where i added 2 ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapters in the pipeline and both have `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)` where we receive a message. The definition of channelRead() is:

```
Calls ChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Object) to forward to the next ChannelInboundHandler in 
the ChanelPipeLine.
```

So this would mean that by implementing channelRead() our message would be sent automatically to the next ChannelInboundHandler's channelRead() method unless we discard(release) our message.

However when my server receives a message from a client only one ChannelInboundHandler receives the message and the message is not forwarded to the second inboundhandler.

I have to manually call `ChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Object)` in the channelRead() method in order for the message to be forwarded to the next ChannelInboundHandler inside the pipeline. Why doesn't the the message get forwarded automatically to the ChannelRead() method in the next inboundhandler like stated in the definition?

Answer (score 0):

Thats expected... You override the `channelRead(...)` method that does what is stated in the javadoc. if you want to forward you either needs to call `super.channelRead(...)` or call `ctx.fireChannelRead(...)` by yourself.